# Java: FHIR condition resource, how do you get abatementDateTime?

Tags: java, hl7-fhir, hapi-fhir

In FHIR 3.x... I have a condition resource and I need to determine how to get to the resolved date.

I read that the field is abatement.abatementDateTime.

I dont see a function to allow to do that.

Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 0):

The `Condition` class has a getter called `getAbatementDateTimeType()` you can use to get that value. It returns a DateTimeType, which has various getters for interacting with the date inside.